# Make density-histogram plot with facet grid so that densities in each facet sum to 1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got the following code which is close to what I want but not quite:

```
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x="gear", fill="cyl"))
p = p + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(cyl~.) 
p
```

That plots a bunch of facets showing the histogram/density relative to the whole population in each facet grid but I'd actually like each facet grid's histogram to be the density relative to that group. How can I do this?

Comment: I've taken a look at your code: it looks like it *is* plotting a histogram for each group. Do you mean you want a different Y-scale for each facet, so they all look the same height?

Comment: @DerwinMcGeary thanks for taking a look. There is a histogram per facet (in this case per cylinder count) but if you add up the densities in a particular facet, they don't sum to 1. I want the density with respect to other members of that facet/cylinder count, not with respect to the total count.

Comment: Even without facet_grid() the frequency plot of geom_histogram() doesn't sum up to 1. Try geom_density().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normalizing faceted histograms separately in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339204/normalizing-faceted-histograms-separately-in-ggplot2)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614720/obtaining-percent-scales-reflective-of-individual-facets-with-ggplot2) is also pretty much the same thing, but note comments on answer that you'd need `binwidth = 1` for the `..density..` solution.